# MariaDB - how to drop partition on master but not on slave

Tags: replication, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I've read about filtering replication and I only run into information I know already, like you can select only a database or a table to do replication on.

My use case is that I want to have a slim and fast master with main data organized into partitions - one partition per day (each day a new partition is created). The master only keeps most recent 10 days of data and I need the slaves to keep all.

How do I `ALTER TABLE ... DROP PARTITION` on master without being replicated on slaves?

I seems to me that somehow I have to instruct the master not to write this operation into bin-log, but how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run `SET SESSION sql_log_bin=0` in the session before running the `ALTER TABLE..`.

Comment: seems my only option from what I could find out. Thank you!